# Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I'm working on converting a string into a hexadecimal and then perform & operation. Here is the scenario which seems to have an issue:

```
byte[] buffer;
string hexoutput;
char[] WaitXMSvalues = WaitXMS.ToCharArray(); // WaitXMS is a textbox, input = 10
foreach (char letter in WaitXMSvalues)
{
     // Get the integral value of the character. 
     int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);

     // Convert the decimal value to a hexadecimal value in string form. 
     hexoutput = String.Format("{0:X}", value);
}            

buffer[0] = Convert.ToByte(hexoutput & 0xFF);
```

throws me an error at the above line:

```
Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'
```

Whats the issue here?

I had done this in my C++ app as follows:

```c++
buffer[0] = WaitXMS->getText().getHexValue32() & 0xFF;
```

and seems to work fine. Whats wrong with my C# code?

Please help!

Comment: Just a detail: The `ToCharArray()` is unnecessary. `class string : IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: I had done it in C++ too and provided code too. So only tagged :)

Comment: Why are you creating an entire method to do this, when `ToString()` is able to handle this on its own, seems silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hexoutput` is a string; there is no defined `&` operation between string and an integer - did you typo in the question? If you are trying to apply a byte-mask, you'll have to do that when the value is some kind of integer/byte; *not* as a string.

For example, the following would work, but would be somewhat pointless:

```
buffer[0] = (byte) (Convert.ToByte(hexoutput, 16) & 0xFF);
```

There's also a significant error in that your `hexoutput` variable is defined **inside** the loop, but accessed outside, again suggesting that the code being shown is **not** the actual code - that would have the compiler error:

> The name 'hexoutput' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry for the typing error. Well hexoutput is declared outside now and this seems to work fine  :)

Comment: And if `WaitXMS` is a `TextBox`, get the text from it through the `WaitXMS.Text` property.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: WaitXMS is a textbox property in my viewmodel class.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to a bitwise **AND** between a string (hexoutput) and an int (0xFF). You can't do that.

But ultimately, if your objective is to have an array of bytes, why are you converting it to a hex formatted string in the first place? You should be able to just:

```
buffer[0] = value & 0xFF;
```